# How does SwiftUI manage state?

Tags: swiftui

I have a UIViewControllerRepresentable [implementation](https://gist.github.com/jfuellert/67e91df63394d7c9b713419ed8e2beb7) and I've noticed that `makeUIViewController` is only called once whereas `init` is called multiple times.

Similarly, the view controller's `init` is called multiple times but the scroll view that it wraps is only created once and `viewDidLoad` is only called once.

Does SwiftUI hold references to controls and then plug them back into new view controller instances? Is there description somewhere of the life cycle?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably only calling `makeUIViewController` if the new view is different from the old view (according to your implementation of `Equatable`).

I think SwiftUI is re-creating the `struct`-based view hierarchy quite often (on state changes) to check if anything changed. Every time this happens, your `init` method is called. But if nothing has changed, SwiftUI won't request a new instance of the ViewController.

Comment: That implementation creates the controller in its init. After the first request, perhaps new controllers aren’t used.